# IOS: Is Chances to give effect while converting abs() to fabs() in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6

Hey I installed **XCode 6.3** and compile my code which is written in **XCode 6.2**. no problem

but now my compiler giving warning named **abs()** function to replace with **fabs()**.

If I done then this will be work in previous versions of my app???

[image]

#### I think:

*abs()* will return an **int value** and

*fabs()* will return **double value**

Answer (score 2):

No, there want be any problem. if you convert from abs() to fabs(). because abs is for 32 bit and fabs for 64 bit.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Exactly!!! that is real meaning its not giving any problem, I replaced and checked....Helpful flag...:)